# Are Checksums for a file same in windows and Linux?

Tags: security, sha1, checksum

I am creating a Sha1 checksum for an apk file in Mac as well as windows. I use the same file while in mac I use this

```
cat AppName.apk |openssl dgst -binary -sha1 | openssl base64 | tr '+/' '-_' |tr -d '=' 
// I get 7pF3C4YCqMHKXOzOep_DW1feJxE
```

In Windows I use various methods mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7) and all of them generate the same checksum.

```
ee91770b8602a8c1ca5cecce7a9fc35b57de2711
```

Why is it different if it is sha1 hash of the same file? or the hash can be both of this? I am confused here. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that Mac command, but you could just simply do `openssl sha1 AppName.apk`.  See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201259

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I wouldn't personally use something like `cat` for reading a binary file.

Comment: @Chris Thompson: openssl can read the file itself and does that in binary mode as well. I'd just prefer to use `shasum` instead of  `openssl sha1 <file>` because the later to me seems to be overblown for that. `shasum` is a standard tool on Unix systems.

Comment: @MatthiasWimmer yep, I'm totally with you. By "this" I meant the Rube Goldberg-esque command for doing it on the Mac

Comment: @ChrisThompson Sorry, I overread the "not" in your sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you use on the Mac does encode the checksum in base64 (which is very uncommon) while on Windows you are encoding the checksum as hex digits.

You can create the SHA-1 checksum on a file using the `shasum` command of OS X:

```
shasum AppName.apk | sed -e 's/ .*//'
```

(The piped call to sed is optional and just serves to remove the filename which is normally added by shasum after the output of the checksum.)

You can even verify that basically both platforms calculated the same checksum and just encoded it differently by transcoding from Base64 to Hex:

```
echo 7pF3C4YCqMHKXOzOep_DW1feJxE= | base64 -D| hexdump
```

Results in:

```
0000000 ee 91 77 0b 86 02 a8 c1 ca 5c ec ce 7a 9f c3 5b
0000010 57 de 27 11
```

Which is the checksum you got on Windows.